# For first time insertion, if Data set has duplicate values, unique index building on mongoose fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I am trying to create a mongoose model as follows:

```
var bookschema = mongoose.Schema({
    path: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    dir: String,
    filename: String,
    size: String,
    type: String,
    related: Array
});

var Books = mongoose.model('Books',bookschema);
```

Now, The first time I am entering data is through Model.create, **the data set array has duplicate keys**.

Thus, the "path" index above is not created. Mongo console reports an error in building the path index but Mongoose shows no error.
*However, (after dropping the database), if I try a small data set (having no duplicate path values), the index gets built correctly*

In such a use case, what is the best way to force the unique index to get built before first insertion through Mongoose? Also, do you think I should report this as an issue in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose reports indexing errors via the `'index'` event on the model.  So to see any errors that occur during the creation of the indexes for `Books` you can add something like:

```
Books.on('index', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Books index error: %s', err);
    }
    else {
        console.info('Books index complete');
    }
});
```

To force a unique index to be created you can add the [`dropDups`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates) option to your index definition, but use that with caution as it will permanently delete any duplicates.

```
var bookschema = mongoose.Schema({
    path: {
        type: String,
        index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}
    },
    dir: String,
    filename: String,
    size: String,
    type: String,
    related: Array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set your unique index using terminal and mongo.
Open a terminal and type this:

```
mongo
use your_db_name
db.books.ensureIndex( { path: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

you can read more about this [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)